# Find all continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\frac{f(x+3)}{3+f(x)}=\frac{4+x^2}{x^2}$

Tags: polynomials, problem-solving, functional-equations

Find all continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ satisfying
$$\frac{f(x+3)}{3+f(x)}=\frac{4+x^2}{x^2}.$$

I believe the original question was
$$\frac{f(x)}{3+f(x)}=\frac{4+x^2}{x^2},$$
which has a simple solution when you simplify.

Comment: Is $f$ supposed to be defined everywhere on $\mathbb{R}$? If so, considering $x=0$, it must be that $f(0)=-3$. From that you can establish values for $f(-3), f(-6),\ldots$.

Comment: Do you know Fourier transform? You can write the equation as $x^2f(x-3)=12+3x^2+4f(x)+x^2f(x)$ and take Fourier transform. Then use [the properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Functional_relationships) of the Fourier transform to get a (differential) equation on $\hat{f}(t)$. Once you have $\hat{f}$ you can transform back and get $f$.

Comment: @Nathanson: Nice idea, but is there any reason to think $f$ has a Fourier transform (even in the sense of tempered distributions)?

Comment: @alex.jordan I guess you have to say $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{R}\setminus\{3\}$. But the idea works when we consider limits, I think. Thanks.

Comment: @Nathanson The original question was a precursor to teaching some highschoolers about solving functional equations, I made an error in typing and got $x+3$. Fourier is beyond the highschool students, but it is an interesting idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many solutions.
Let $h\colon[0,3]\to\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ be *any* continuous function such that $$\tag1h(3)=\frac13+\frac49h(0).$$
Now define $g\colon[0,3]\to\mathbb R$,
$$ \tag2g(x)=x^2h(x)-3.$$
We can define $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by letting $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x\in[0,3]$ and otherwise definig recursively
$$\tag3f(x)=\frac{4+(x-3)^2}{(x-3)^2}(f(x-3)+3)\qquad\text{for $x>3$} $$
and
$$\tag4f(x)=\frac{x^2}{4+x^2}f(x+3)-3\qquad\text{for $x<0$}.$$
Continuity for $f$ follows, it need only be checked at $x=0$ from the left and at $x=3$ from the right.
And indeed, from $(4)$ we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=-3=f(0)$$
and 
$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 3^+}f(x)&\stackrel{(2)}=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}\left(\frac{4+\delta^2}{\delta^2}(g(\delta)+3)\right)\\&\stackrel{(2)}=\lim_{\delta\to 0^+}(4+\delta^2)h(\delta)\\&=4h(0)\stackrel{(1)}=9h(3)-3\stackrel{(2)}=g(3)=f(3).\end{align}$$